# Web Browser permissions to run JavaFX application

Tags: windows-8.1, java

I'm using the Netbeans IDE to create a simple HelloWorld gui application in JavaFX. Netbeans offers three run configurations and two of those are, run in a Web Browser or run in WebStart. When I try either of those run configurations I get a message saying, "Application Blocked By Security Settings".

Will I need to modify security settings in *Configure Java* or in my Windows Security settings. Will my anti-malware software affect this as well? Do I also need to change any Web Browser settings e.g., Chrome settings?

I am using Java 8, Windows 8.1, and the Chrome Browser.

Here is a snippet of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you  must modify the security level:
http://java.com/en/download/help/win_controlpanel.xml

then configure the Exception Site List:

Click on the Edit Site List button.
Click the Add in the Exception Site List window.
Click in the empty field under Location field to enter the URL. 
URL should begin with http:// or https://
eg. http://myexample.com
Click OK to save the URL that you entered. If you click Cancel, the URLs are not saved.
Click Continue on the Security Warning dialog.

Comment: I will try this solution in the coming days hang tight for an accepted response, thanks.